# Enable copy/paste for SSRS report in preview mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

How can we enable the copy/paste option for ssrs report content in preview mode? Now in my report, I don't get a copy/paste menu in mouse right click.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot copy text from a report in preview mode; it has never been an option in any version of the tool that I have worked with. I have often wished it was. Pasting, of course, would never be an option.

Work around: export the results to Excel, or PDF, and copy from that output. Or, deploy the report to your reporting server, and work with the results there. Once the report is open in a browser using Report Manager, you can select and copy the results all you like.

Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but likely the only true answer. I would *love* to be wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Richards answer is the best answer and upvoted. When you can easily export report data in any format then why you want to copy and paste from the preview mode? if you still want to have a feel of preview mode, you can take screenshots and then probably apply some OCR?

Otherwise, just to add value to Richard's answer above, **you can export the report (data) in the preview mode using export button displayed in the  screen below**  and you can choose any format of your choice:

[image]

sounds good?